# Knockout: start observableArray with null

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Seems that in knockout 3.2.0 they changed the behavior of ObservableArrays. In knockout 2, if I did:

```
var array = ko.observableArray(null)
console.log(array())
```

It would return me null. The same thing on knockout 3.2.0 doesn't happen because the observable array instead of null is create as an empty array.

This is my case:

```
<div>
 <div class="spinner" data-bind="visible: comments() == null">
 <!-- ko foreach: comments -->
 ...
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I'd like to start showing in the comments div a spinner, and when the comments are populated, i'll hide the spinner and show the comments. I can't do `data-bind="visible: comments().length == 0"` because if the post has no comments, the comments array will have 0 length and the spinner will be shown forever.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Whatever you use to populate the array should set a flag when it's done.

Comment: This was "fixed" with this issue: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/733 and also https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1054

Comment: If you still want to old behavior you can explicitly set your observableArray to null after you have created it: `var array = ko.observableArray(null); array(null);
console.log(array())` will log null

Comment: are you using ajax to load comments? I typically define a function like `isLoading = function(show){ $('.loading-div').toggle(show)};` then from my loading function I call `isLoading(true)` to start the spinner and in `$.ajax().always(function(){ isLoading(false) });`

Comment: godmode the problem is that would trigger the loading div of all comments. Each post has it's own comments div with it's own spinner

Comment: @godmode You should use a property on the view model such as isLoading and then the visible binding to control the display based on this property. Your solution is the query way of doing it, not the way you would do it using Knockout.js

Comment: I don't think creating an observable for each post to track the loading state of the comments are a good idea. What if there's 30 posts on the page?

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
self.comments = ko.observableArray([]);

<!-- ko if: comments().length > 0 -->
Greater than zero // Show spinner
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: comments().length > 0 -->
No greater than zero // No spinner needed
<!-- /ko -->
```

Let me know what you think.